# How many ways to pick $4$ numbers (without repetition) from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ such that the sum of the $4$ numbers is equal to $28$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways to pick $4$ numbers (without repetition) from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ such that the sum of the $4$ numbers is equal to $28$?

Is there a nice way to approach this problem rather than just trying to count all possible combinations?

Comment: No: the answers are {4, 7, 8, 9} and {5, 6, 8, 9}.

Comment: Well, you can never use 1, 2, or 3 and make it up to 28. So you might as well ask for the number of ways to choose 4 numbers from {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} that add to 28. And all six of those numbers add to 39; so you can focus on the pair of numbers to leave out, and ask how many pairs from {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} add to $39-28=11$. Then you're pretty much done.

Answer (score 2):

Since the sum of the 4 numbers is 28, their average is 7; so the sum of the distances to 7 of the numbers greater than 7 must equal the sum of the distances to 7 of the numbers less than 7.

If only one of 8 or 9 is selected, this is not possible; so the 4 numbers must include both 8 and 9.

1) If 7 is selected, the remaining number must be 4.

2) If 7 is not selected, then the other numbers must be 5 and 6

(since the sum of their distances to 7 must be 3).